# Getting average of column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to be able to read a file where I will pull what the name of the location is and then calculate the average amount of snow they get.
This is what I have so far.

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('filteredData.csv')
if ('NAME' == 'ADA 0.7 SE, MI US'):
    data.ix['1/1/2016':'12/31/2016']
    newdata=data['SNOW'].mean()
```

I am still unsure if doing this would be better by grouping the name of the locations and then calculating the average snow that way.

Please be patient with me I'm still brand new to pandas.

This image is just one part of twenty different locations:
[image: This image is just one part of twenty different locations]

Comment: No, this would not be better than grouping on name and calculating the average snow.

Comment: See Pandas docs on [split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine)

Comment: Also maybe copy and paste the result from `print(data.sample(10))` (or give us `data.sample(10).to_csv('sample.csv')`) instead of posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can use `groupby()`:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Create test data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["place1", "place1", "place1", "place2", "place2", "place2"] * 2,
    "date": ["1/1/2016", "1/2/2016", "1/3/2016"] * 2 + ["1/1/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/3/2017"] * 2,
    "snow": [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1000.0, 2000.0, 3000.0]
    })
# Transform string date to datetime format
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

`df` looks like:

```
         date    name    snow
0  2016-01-01  place1    10.0
1  2016-01-02  place1    20.0
2  2016-01-03  place1    30.0
3  2016-01-01  place2   100.0
4  2016-01-02  place2   200.0
5  2016-01-03  place2   300.0
6  2017-01-01  place1     0.0
7  2017-01-02  place1     1.0
8  2017-01-03  place1     2.0
9  2017-01-01  place2  1000.0
10 2017-01-02  place2  2000.0
11 2017-01-03  place2  3000.0
```

Then calculate the average amount of snow for a certain group, in this case, I've grouped by name and year:

```
# Group dataset by name of place and year, calculate the average amount of snow for each group
df["snow_average"] = df.groupby(["name", df.date.dt.year])["snow"].transform("mean")
```

`df` now looks like:

```
         date    name    snow  snow_average
0  2016-01-01  place1    10.0          20.0
1  2016-01-02  place1    20.0          20.0
2  2016-01-03  place1    30.0          20.0
3  2016-01-01  place2   100.0         200.0
4  2016-01-02  place2   200.0         200.0
5  2016-01-03  place2   300.0         200.0
6  2017-01-01  place1     0.0           1.0
7  2017-01-02  place1     1.0           1.0
8  2017-01-03  place1     2.0           1.0
9  2017-01-01  place2  1000.0        2000.0
10 2017-01-02  place2  2000.0        2000.0
11 2017-01-03  place2  3000.0        2000.0
```

You can change your `groupby()` criteria according to what you're looking for. I used `name` and year because that's what it looks like you want, judging by your example.

**EDIT:**
My apologies, I got frustrated. You seem to have misunderstood my answer, and that you needed to create a new dataframe manually. You can use your dataset from the csv file, and do the same commands as above, but apply them to your dataset, which you call `data`:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('filteredData.csv')

# Transform string date to datetime format
data["date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["date"])
print data

# Group dataset by name of place and year, calculate the average amount of snow for each group
data["snow_average"] = data.groupby(["name", data.date.dt.year])["snow"].transform("mean")
print data
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking at sorting by the location name and the year. In your example "date": ["1/1/2016", "1/2/2016", "1/3/2016"] * 2 + ["1/1/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/3/2017"] * 2, would I need to input every date that is in the record book or am I able to say any dates between 1/1/2016 to 12/31/2016?

Comment: `groupby(["name", df.date.dt.year])` groups data points by, well, name and year. So every data point that has the same name and year will be grouped together before calculating the mean amount of snow. In my example, this results in four different groups: 

1: "place1" in 2016, 
2: "place2" in 2016,
3: "place1" in 2017, and
4: "place2" in 2017. 
You don't need to input every date in the record book, it will extract the year from your dates during grouping.

Comment: I guess I still don't follow. I have a csv file that has close to 15,000 entries and from what I'm experiencing from the guideline that you have shared with me is that I will have to enter in each entry. What I was trying to do though is import a file called filteredData.csv and be able to pull the name, date, and snow to be able to group those together and find the average snowfall for that year in each location. If I didn't make that clear in my initial comment then that is my bad or if I'm not understanding your previous comment then would you please try to explain it again.

Comment: I understood you the first time. And I will, for the third time, tell you that the `groupby()` function does exactly that. Have you tried it yet? You tell the `groupby()` function: "Hey, please group this entire dataset by name and the year-part of the dates, then calculate the mean snow amount for each group and present it as a new column, called 'snow_average'". You don't have to manually enter each data point. The first part of my answer is just to create sample data to work with. My `df` is the same as your `data`, just replace `df` with `data` and you'll be fine.